# Parallel execution of a function | No async await as no awaiting required

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Execute a function N number of times in parallel. Here i want to execute function fun in parallel.

```
function fun(){
    for(let j=0; j < 100; j++){
        console.log("i");
  }
}

var start =  Date.now();
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        fun();
  //  setTimeout(fun(), 100); --> Tried this way
}
console.log("ending in " + - ( start - Date.now()) / 1000 + 'seconds');
```

JSFiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/Gourishankar/p4t6w73x/15/

It seems to be a very basic problem for optimization but i am not able to conclude/find a full proof solution.

-> Does Service worker solves this ? or only way to solve such problem ?
-> Is there any other way ?

I have similar real problem where while doing paste on ag-grid setter function is called multiple times with different params. I want to optimize that.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You cannot do this in Javascript, at least not yet. Making the function run faster is almost certainly your best bet. Javascript has only one method of parallel execution (web workers), and the communication/serialization overhead will almost certainly swamp any gains you make from using it.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/155050) for sure, and that's not a good thing. You are asking about a problem that is completely abstracted away from your real problem to do with ag-grid.

Comment: I disagree, if i make my setter function run in parallel for each row then my task is done, that's what i believe, correct me if i am thinking wrong.

Comment: You are wrong, please read the link above more carefully. Your question is like the poster child of all "XY problem" questions. If you think otherwise, have fun exploring service workers (you probably mean web workers).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript uses a single-threaded execution model. To do concurrent calculations (i.e. have more than one thread of execution), your only option is (multiple?) web workers.

The discussion around whether this is an appropriate solution is not covered by this answer.